# Can't install google-cloud-aiplatform on Apple M1 silicon - Fails on grpcio

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pip, apple-m1

Trying to install `google-cloud-aiplatform` on a Macbook with the M1 Pro chip and it gets stuck trying to install the `grpcio` dependency.

I am running `pip install google-cloud-aiplatform` from a Miniforge environment running python 3.9.13.

The error trace is massive, and I can edit to share more if needed but the last few lines say:

```
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> grpcio

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this annoying issue by using `pyenv` (with python 3.10) rather than `Miniforge` and installing version 1.44.0 of `grpcio` before `google-cloud-aiplatform`. I do not know why this works, so if anybody can shed some light into it that would be great! But if you need to get it working and are ok using `pyenv` then below are the steps I took (I used `brew` to install `pyenv`):

- Install `brew` and follow the instructions to update your PATH etc.

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

- Install pyenv and set python version `3.10.3` as the global version:

```
brew install pyenv
pyenv global 3.10.3
```

- (Optional) Use `pyenv-virtualenv` to create your environment:

```
brew install pyenv-virtualenv
pyenv virtualenv 3.10.3 your_env_name
pyenv activate your_env_name
```

- Upgrade pip and install `grpcio`:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install -v https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/65/75/8b706e1170e2c7b6242b1675259e47986bb4fc490f29387989a965972e6e/grpcio-1.44.0.tar.gz
```

- Install `google-cloud-aiplatform`:

```
pip install google-cloud-aiplatform
```

Hope this helps!